# How to link 2 lists, sort 1 and have the other follow

Tags: python, list, sorting

I need to sort 1 list and have some values in another list follow the order of the 1st list for eg

```
list1=[5,3,1,4,2]
list2=[2014,2015,2016,2017,2018]
```

I need list1 to sort by accending order and the values in list2 will change order accordingly, so eg

```
list1=[1,2,3,4,5]
list2=[2016,2018,2015,2017,2014]
```

Comment: Please don't bypass the need to provide information by just duplicating the same thing. Show your efforts in research, what you have tried, and what happened.

Comment: You should not have two lists, instead e.g. `zip` them together and then sort based on some condition.